# Baking And Unwrapping Alpha

Tags: uv, transparency, texture-baking, procedural, mirror-modifier

i wanted to ask a qustion, so i just created a procedural "rorschach" like material, and to do it i used only 1/4 of a spehere and mirrored it to x y z plane, so the texture can have 4 side symetry, the question is, how do i bake it? since its only unwrapping 1/4 of the sphere.

if i apply mirror modifier, and unwrap it, then the texture wont be symetrical.

the second question is, how do i bake alpha because my texture is partially transparent

the texture looks like this in cycles rendered view [image: my rorschach procedural texture]

here i put [google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19p9D1V1DBxAIaFE4D0F1I1cYy-ybSSm8?usp=share_link) link for u guys to look at the blender files

Thankyou in adnvace!

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several UV slots !
Add a new UV slot, in the mesh panel, and unwrap your sphere fully.
You will bake to this slot, so make sure it's enabled for rendering, with the camera icon checked next to it.

Your noise texture will need to find and use the mirrored UV layout, so add a UVMap node, and plug it in.

[image: example]

Now when you bake, it will bake *from* the mirrored UVs, *to* the full UVs

And to bake alpha, best practice is to plug the value directly into Surface output and bake with `Emission` type. This will bake only color data, and no shading.